# HTML & CSS: When to use ID and Class?

Tags: html, css, styles

I want to know when to use ID and Class properly. I use ID when selecting in js (if needs to be unique) and Class only for the Css styling/design.

I want to know if there's other significance in using ID and Class or If I'm using it wrong or improper.

I just want to know your opinion or how you're using it. Feel free to answer!

Thank you

Comment: This question is very broad and probably off-topic for Stack Overflow. You can simply google "html id" and "html class" and find tons of information. In particular, visit the MDN pages on these topics. That's generally a reliable source for good quality information.

Comment: Thank you sir. I just want your opinions or how you're using it

Comment: class can be very useful in jquery too when you have lots of elements that have the same jquery behavior..

Comment: Well, there you go. Questions seeking opinions are [not permitted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a good question for StackOverflow and I recommend in the future that you use google before asking questions.

The key difference between classes and IDs are ID's are unique. Classes are not unique.

You can use any number of classes per element. ie: `class="btn btn-primary"` but you have only have one ID per element. ie: `id="button-23"`.

The biggest difference comes into play when you start using Javascript to interact with the DOM. If I use `document.getElementById("button-23")` and you have 2 elements with that ID, Javascript will only interact with the first one it encounters.

In general, in my opinion, especially when you are starting out, stick with classes and don't use IDs.

Answer (score 0):

Id is for unique elements. There should be only one element with given id while there can be as many elements with same class as you want.

For example let's take a login form. There is only one of id #login and #password but both of them can have class .login-form-input.

So use id when you need to pinpoint certain element and class when need describe some group of elements.